Refactoring C# Winform Application
I've been charged with refactoring a C# Winform application that had all the methods in one class in the form file.  I've created a new class and moved several of the methods to this class (after some re-writes), but I'm unsuccessful moving any of the methods that reference form fields directly - i.e. TextBoxOne.Text = "abc".  (the errors appear below)
To find a solution, I created a simplfiled test case.
namespace UpdateFormData
{
    public partial class ParentForm : Form
    {
        public ParentForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Field manipulation
        public void UpdateField1()
        {
            // do something meaningful
            tbField1.Text = "Field 1 - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        public void UpdateField2()
        {
            // do something meaningful
            tbField2.Text = "Field 2 - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        // Message
        public void ShowMsg(int PassNo)
        {
            string MsgTitle = PassNo == 1 ? "First" : "Second";
            string Fld1Txt = tbField1.Text;
            string Fld2Txt = tbField2.Text;
            MessageBox.Show($"Field 1: {Fld1Txt}\nField 2: {Fld2Txt}", $"{MsgTitle} Message");
        }
        // Test Button
        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int PassNo = 1;
            string Fld1Txt = tbField1.Text;
            string Fld2Txt = tbField2.Text;

            ShowMsg(PassNo);
            UpdateField1();
            UpdateField2();
            PassNo++;
            ShowMsg(PassNo);
        }

        private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbField1.Text = "Field 1";
            tbField2.Text = "Field 2";
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}

This code does exactly as expected.  However when I move the methods UpdateField1, UpdateField2, and ShowMsg to a new class (Utilities), the form fields are not recognized.
namespace UpdateFormData
{
    public partial class ParentForm : Form
    {
        public ParentForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Test Button
        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int PassNo = 1;
            string Fld1Txt = tbField1.Text;
            string Fld2Txt = tbField2.Text;

            Utilities.ShowMsg(PassNo);
            Utilities.UpdateField1();
            Utilities.UpdateField2();
            PassNo++;
            Utilities.ShowMsg(PassNo);
        }

        private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbField1.Text = "Field 1";
            tbField2.Text = "Field 2";
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}

namespace UpdateFormData
{
    internal static class Utilities
    {

        // Field manipulation
        public static void UpdateField1()
        {
            // do something meaningful
            ParentForm.tbField1.Text = "Field 1 - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        public static void UpdateField2()
        {
            // do something meaningful
            ParentForm.tbField2.Text = "Field 2 - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        // Message
        public static void ShowMsg(int PassNo)
        {
            string MsgTitle = PassNo == 1 ? "First" : "Second";
            string Fld1Txt = ParentForm.tbField1.Text;
            string Fld2Txt = ParentForm.tbField2.Text;
            MessageBox.Show($"Field 1: {Fld1Txt}\nField 2: {Fld2Txt}", $"{MsgTitle} Message");
        }
        // Test Button
        private static void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int PassNo = 1;
            string Fld1Txt = ParentForm.tbField1.Text;
            string Fld2Txt = ParentForm.tbField2.Text;

            ShowMsg(PassNo);
            UpdateField1();
            UpdateField2();
            PassNo++;
            ShowMsg(PassNo);
        }
    }
}

Here are the compile errors.
Error(active)  CS0122  'ParentForm.tbField1' is inaccessible due to its protection level    UpdateFormData  D:\UpdateFormData\Utilities.cs  11
Error(active)  CS0122  'ParentForm.tbField2' is inaccessible due to its protection level    UpdateFormData  D:\UpdateFormData\Utilities.cs  16
Error(active)  CS0122  'ParentForm.tbField1' is inaccessible due to its protection level    UpdateFormData  D:\UpdateFormData\Utilities.cs  23
Error(active)  CS0122  'ParentForm.tbField2' is inaccessible due to its protection level    UpdateFormData  D:\UpdateFormData\Utilities.cs  24
Error(active)  CS0122  'ParentForm.tbField1' is inaccessible due to its protection level    UpdateFormData  D:\UpdateFormData\Utilities.cs  31
Error(active)  CS0122  'ParentForm.tbField2' is inaccessible due to its protection level    UpdateFormData  D:\UpdateFormData\Utilities.cs  32

What do I need to do to make the ParentForm fields accessible and updateable?  Thanks in advance.

One simple option is to make them public. You can do this in designer - find the "Modifiers" property. However, making them public exposes them to other classes. So, this may not be the best design.

The code you've posted seems rather pointless - it doesn't really do anything. Also, in btnTest_Click, what's the point of  int PassNo = 1; and then later  PassNo++;? Is this your actual code or your attempt at creating a minimal reproducible example? Any refactoring of the existing code, doesn't require creating a new class, but rather eliminating pointless methods and variables. You may benefit by taking a step back, and re-thinking the logic. Try writing some pseudo-code.

There is no point in such refactoring. Moving code from form event handlers into static Utility class and then calling such methods from form event handlers.. why? What does such change brings? Don't do that. A correct refactoring would be to detect logic and extract it into unit-testable classes. This will give you unit-testing power. Another refactoring option is removing all data from the form: using MVVM or similar pattern  to abstract data from viewing them and having possibility to manipulate data without form at all (e.g. with API).

As per @001 comment, expose all form properties as public or make Utilities class nested in ParentForm (this trick gives it access to all private members of the form). And as a minimal refactoring requirement, don't put event hanlders (btnTest_Click) in that class: the form should subscribe to events, contain event handlers and from there you can call an utility method with clear signature (no ..Args or senders).

This sample code is only presented as a depiction of the issue - not a working application.  The methods that will exist in the Utility class read data from the network, manipulate that data, and save the results back to the network based on the data that the user inputs into the forms (in ParentForm).  I didn't feel posting 1200 lines of code would provide much clarity.

Per 001's suggestion, I've set all the Modifier properties to Public for all controls on the form, and still no success.  Is there something more I should have done?

Is there something more I should have done?: Not followed that advice. Just because you read something on the internet, doesn't mean it's something you should do.

I've been through this situation and preferred to implement an MVC pattern (Model View Controller) leaving the view like this:
View:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public YourController Controller;

    public TextBox TextBoxLogradouro
    {
        get { return txtBoxLogradouro; }
    }
}

Controller
public class YourController
{
    private readonly Form1 View;
    public void SetValue(string value)
    {
        View.TextBoxLogradouro.Text = value;
    }
}

Then you can create your model and use it in your controller.
